# Помогите разобраться в позиционировании в  jQuery .position()

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, html, javascript

Добра всем!

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с позиционирование в jQuery. Сразу к примеру ибо писать красиво не умею

есть некий html код, назовем его поле в котором будем позиционировать элемент и сам элемент

```
<div id="workplace" class="field">
  <div id="pos">Hello world</div>
</div>
```

Зададим стиль

```
.field {
  width: 550px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top:350px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Кнопкой будем менять позицию

```
<button onclick="groupAligment();">Pos</button>
```

Фукция меняет позицию

```
function groupAligment() {
  var vertical = document.getElementById('pos').offsetTop;
  window.console.log(vertical);
  $('#pos').position({
    of: document.getElementById('workplace'),
    at: "center top+"+vertical+"",
    my: "center top"
  });
}
```

Позиция меняется и все как бы хорошо работает, но наверное я что-то не дочитал/ недопонял, с каждым вызовом функции позиция сдвигается вверх на один пиксель,

Браузеры: FF, Opera, Chrome, Safari все одинаково, а в ie 8 все нормально.

Буду очень благодарен за любой совет, тыкните носом, если кто знает.

Спасибо.

Comment: ВСЕ ДЕЛО В 

     border: 1px solid black;

это и есть магия...))))

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло